# Child accordion Firing Parent accordion accordionactivate event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an accordion and when a panel is opened it gets html from the server which it renders as an accordion as a child of the previous accordion. When I click on the child accordion it fires the parent onactivate event

```
@model IEnumerable<String>

@{
    Layout = null;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            font: normal 13px auto "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #4f6b72;
            background: #E6EAE9;
        }

        a {
            color: #c75f3e;
        }

        #mytable 
        {
            width: 1400px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        th {
            font: bold 13px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #4f6b72;
            border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
            border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
            background: #CAE8EA url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
        }

        th.nobg {
            border-top: 0;
            border-left: 0;
            border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
            background: none;
        }

        td {
            border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 3px 3px 3px 6px;
            color: #4f6b72;
        }


        td.alt {
            background: #F5FAFA;
            color: #797268;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        @Html.Hidden("SelectedDate", ViewData["SelectedDate"])
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.TextBox("DateSelector", "", new { style = "display:table-cell; width:90%", @id = "DatePicker" })
            <input type="submit" value="Get"/>
            <br />
            <div id="Nxts" class="accordion">
                @foreach (var nxtFileName in Model)
                {
                    <h3>@*<img src="@if (item.ExtractedSuccessfully()){<text>../../Images/GreenTick.png</text>} else{<text>../../Images/RedCross.png</text>}"/>*@ @nxtFileName </h3>
                        <div></div>
                }
            </div>

        }

</body>
</html>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#DatePicker").datepicker();
    });

    function PopulatePanel(selectedPanel, NxtFileLocation,Date) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ExtractedXMLFiles", "Summary")',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            data: { "NxtFileLocation": NxtFileLocation, "Date": Date },
            success: function (result) {
                selectedPanel.append(result);
                SetupAccordion();
            }
        });
    }

    function SetupAccordion() {
        $(".accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        $(".accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content", 
            active: false
        });
        $("#Nxts").on("accordionactivate", function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.newPanel.length > 0) {
                if (ui.newPanel.html() == "") {
                    var date = $('#SelectedDate').val();
                    var active = $("#Nxts").accordion("option", "active");
                    var text = $.trim($("#Nxts h3").eq(active).text());
                    PopulatePanel(ui.newPanel, text, date);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of event bubling, means a event triggered by a child element will bubble all the way upto the document object.

In your case you need to test whether the element in which the event was fired was the using the events `target` property or use the `ui`'s new header.

Then

```
    $("#Nxts").on("accordionactivate", function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.newHeader).parent().is('#Nxts') && ui.newPanel.length > 0) {
            if (ui.newPanel.html() == "") {
                var date = $('#SelectedDate').val();
                var active = $("#Nxts").accordion("option", "active");
                var text = $.trim($("#Nxts h3").eq(active).text());
                PopulatePanel(ui.newPanel, text, date);
            }
        }
    });
```

Problem: [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DH7S47?p=preview)
Solution: [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdjxSB?p=preview)

To prevent event propagation from child accordions

```
$("#Nxts").on("accordionactivate", '.accordion', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation():
});
```

Comment: Is there no way to stop the child from firing the parents event?

Comment: @user351709 you can stop the propagation of child events